# Does playing chess with a real board help improvement more than play online?

Tags: learning, online, otb-chess

I read somewhere that playing and making moves otb is better than online for improvement. Is this true?

Comment: If you plan to play tournaments which are played on a physical board, you should practice with a physical board. Otherwise you will find yourself "blind". If you only play online, sticking to it is fine.

Answer (score 2):

I play most (>95%) of my games online, and when I play with a real board, I find a bit difficult to translate positions I already played and the visual pattern matching of tactical situations takes longer. Not to look at the board then, helps a bit.

So, I think, when you prepare for a board tournament, or something like this, preparing on a real board will help. When you only play online all the time, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

They're pretty much the same thing once you get used to both, specially for long games. In Blitz, you'll be able to move a bit faster or slower depending on how much you've practiced and the difference could be critical.